Apply outline border only to range of cells with openpyxl
I'm looking to apply an outline border to a range of cells using openpyxl.
I've seen articles describing how to iterate over cells in a range & apply a border to each cell - this is not what I need.
Below is my code to define the border, but I cannot see how to apply it to a range/selection of cells.
thickBorder = openpyxl.styles.borders.Border(left=openpyxl.styles.borders.Side(style="thick"),
                                           right=openpyxl.styles.borders.Side(style="thick"),
                                           top=openpyxl.styles.borders.Side(style="thick"),
                                           bottom=openpyxl.styles.borders.Side(style="thick"),
                                           outline=True
                                           )

I've also tried adding a border to a range, but this doesn't work.
myRange = ws["B4":"Y6"]
myRange.border = thickBorder

Any suggestions?

Openpyxl does things cell by cell. There is no function provided with the module to accept a range and apply to the cells for you. But you can certainly create your own. If you search SO for '[openpyxl] borders range' you will probably find some examples that probably work.

From this answer
You can do operations over a range of cells using the cell_rangemodule (from the worksheet module).
A CellRange object has a few useful properties you can leverage to do what you want:
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange
import openpyxl.styles.borders import Border, Side

range = CellRange("B4:Y6")
for row, col in range.cells:
    top = Side(style="thick") if (row, col) in range.top else None
    left = Side(style="thick") if (row, col) in range.left else None
    right = Side(style="thick") if (row, col) in range.right else None
    bottom = Side(style="thick") if (row, col) in range.bottom else None
    ws.cell(row, col).border = bd.Border(left, right, top, bottom, outline=True)
  


Using openpyxl, You need to process cell by cell, and apply the changes.
I would suggest the following code to apply border.:
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side

# Define the border
thickBorder = Border(
    left=Side(style="thick"),
    right=Side(style="thick"),
    top=Side(style="thick"),
    bottom=Side(style="thick")
)

# Load the workbook and select the worksheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('your_workbook.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
    
# Define the range
start_row, start_col = 4, 2  # B4
end_row, end_col = 6, 25     # Y6
    
# Apply the border to each cell in the range
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=start_row, max_row=end_row, min_col=start_col, max_col=end_col):
for cell in row:
    cell.border = thickBorder
    
# Save the workbook
wb.save('your_workbook_with_borders.xlsx')

